# DataGridView Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

So, I am trying to rig a DataGridView so that when the enter key is pressed on the last cell of the last row, a new row will be added. I can't seem to get this to work, as the DataGridView controls don't seem to respond to any key events when enter key is pressed on the last row. Is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: I do not know why u ask this question, the standard behaviour of a dgv is exactly what u want..

Comment: not when you are on the last row, enter key will work fine if you are up anywhere in the table besides the last row. But if you are on the last row, enter key is ignored.

Comment: I meant, when u have edited and entered a new value in the last row, then an additional row is created. I think u r talking of the situation where u have entered nothing in the last row, but just pressing enter right?

Comment: Oh I gotcha, no I turned off the AllowUsersToAddRows property, that behavior wasn't working right for my needs either.

Comment: Hmmm, thats the ideal way to do. If `AllowUsersToAddRows` doesnt help you, then you should post that as a question. Its better to tackle the right way..

Comment: Did you try handling DataGridView.KeyDown event ? it can be totally achieved

Comment: Yes, the key events don't fire when you are in the last row of the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the ENTER key.  
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Add another if statement and use some logic to see if it is the cell you want then create your new row if true!
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }
```

More info here: [DataGridView.ProcessDataGridViewKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdatagridviewkey.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I had considered that, but it requires extending to a custom control, is there anyway to manage with the base DataGridView?

Comment: Not that I know of mate, but I'm sure someone else may be able to answer that!

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out, I never like extending DGV, it acts funny on column adding, maybe Im doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior like this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int value = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
            {
                new DataColumn("column1", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("column2", typeof(int)),
            });

        dt.Rows.Add("row " + value, value++);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && 
            cell.RowIndex == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 && 
            cell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
            dt.Rows.Add("row " + value, value++);
    }
```

this is a databinded gridview, of course you can add rows to an unbinded data grid view itself.

Comment: I tried this first thing. It doesn't work, for whatever reason, the Key events don't register on the last row. Even tab doesn't fire the event. Tab will work, by what I estimate is some logic in the base class, but it does not fire the key events when on the last row.

Comment: Do you by any chance have used a toolstrip menu item with shortcut key of Enter? or maybe KeyDown event is captured before it's bubbled down to the gridview?

Comment: I'll double check that, but I dont think so. I'm having the same problem on just a simple test form with no extra programming.